# Is there a way to add "manually" assemblies to .NET the way clr.addReference does?

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, python.net

It has been some time now that I have been stuck in my program because it crashes at `import clr` when I launch the `.exe` of it.

Is there another way to do what `clr.addReference('myDll')` does but manually and make .NET know of my dll?